# Does it make a difference to change the order of JOIN ON condition?

Tags: sql, join, left-join

Assume that I have a table `EMPLOYEES` that has 100,000 rows.
And I have `DEPENDENTS` table which has 200,000 rows.

I can obtain a list of all dependents with their relation from employees table (`EMPLOYEES` has a column `EMP_ID` which is a foreign key in `DEPENDENTS` with the name `PARENT_EMP_ID`).

```
SELECT
    D.FIRST_NAME,
    D.LAST_NAME,
    E.EMPLOYEE_NAME AS DEPENDENT_OF
 FROM
    DEPENDENTS D
    LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEES E ON D.PARENT_EMP_ID = E.EMP_ID
```

My question is:
Would it make any difference if I joined the table like this:

```
...
FROM DEPENDENTS D 
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEES E ON D.PARENT_EMP_ID = E.EMP_ID
```

versus:

```
...
FROM DEPENDENTS D 
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEES E ON E.EMP_ID = D.PARENT_EMP_ID
```

Notice, that I have changed the order of the condition, preserving the order of the tables themselves since I need all rows from dependents (not caring if I get duplicates from EMPLOYEES table).

Comment: No difference at all

Comment: There *is* no (logical) order in the condition. The order is `DEPENDENTS LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEES`. Reversing *that* is a semantic change. How you write down your condition is not. The optimizer will not change its plan based on that.

Comment: If you are looking to improve performance, ask yourself why you are using a left join instead of an inner join.

Comment: I would appreciate it for the person who down-voted my question to elaborate the reason. I searched for the answer to my question and could not find it anywhere.

Comment: The mouseover text for the downvote arro includes "does not show any reserarch effort". Your question is absolutely fundamental & you could read any intro or google re select, join, on, execution etc & words you found.  You don't say what kind of difference you might mean, eg logical evaluation order & what the query returns,  vs performance differences. If you searched summarize it & what you found. Say what reference(s) you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any logical join would be converted to one of the below physical join..

- nested loops
- hash join
- merge join

For all the above physical joins,each is implemented differently and changing clause like the way you changed doesn't matter

for the below join you have..

```
E.EMP_ID = D.PARENT_EMP_ID
```

if we assume ,SQL picked hash join for your query..in this case sql chooses table which has less rows as the build table and it will use this table to probe into other table..

even though you change joins ,it doesn't matter

Answer (score -1):

NO,there will be no change at all because the elements of table DEPENDENTS are being compared to the elements of table EMPLOYEES keeping DEPENDENTS table as the base table in both the cases, so the order of the condition does not matter.But if the order of the base table is changed than the results will differ for both the cases.

Comment: Order within a row has nothing to do with order of rows. But tables re not ordered. Implementations have order, if you were addressing that, but you're not. Also read more good & bad answers to similar questions to learn more about the difference. Also make sure your answer actually explains & justifies. And that you know what you're talking about.